# Knockout: If binding callback not working

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

I have a simple knockout component but my if binding is not working and I dont know why.

My template is the following:

```
<!-- ko if (getAlcContent($parent) > 0) -->
<div class="detail details-alc-content">
    <span class="value">
        <span data-bind="text: getAlcContent($parent)"></span>% Vol. Alc.
    </span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And my Component:

```
/* ... */

getAlcContent: function(quoteItem) {
    var item = this.getItem(quoteItem.item_id);
    return item && parseFloat(item.alc_content) ? item.alc_content : undefined;
},

/* ... */
```

But the `div.detail` is always rendered even if I returned `undefined`. I have also tried `false`, `0` and `getAlcContent($parent) > 0`.

Why is it like this?
On the knockout page it says any expression that evaluates to true or truish which is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo there, try

```
<!-- ko if: getAlcContent($parent) > 0 -->
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it.